# RadioGroup not passing the accurate value to the parent state

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a radiogroup with radio buttons that are initially unchecked, but when I do checked them, the value of the state is one off the value of the checked button. I'm using Material UI

Here's a sample of what happens

```
const initialValues = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    gender: ''
};
const [state, setState] = useState(initialValues);
const handler = (e) => {
    setState({
        ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
}
return (
    <ChildComponent handler={handler} {...state} />
)
```

Then, in the `<ChildComponent />`

```
const { fristName, lastName, gender, handler } = props;
return (
    <FormControl component='fieldset'>
        <RadioGroup onChange={handler} name='gender' value={gender}>
            <FormControlLabel value='feminine' control={<Radio />} label='Feminine' />
            <FormControlLabel value='masculine' control={<Radio />} label='Masculine />
            <FromControlLabel value='others' control={<Radio />} label='Others />
        </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
)
```

The `<ChildComponent />`'s local copy of the `gender` state, when logged in the console, is correct, however, the parent state seems to get delayed when updating.

When the `feminine` value is checked, the parent state remains empty, but the child state updates. When the `masculine` value is checked, the parent state updates to `feminine`, but the child state updates correctly to `masculine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code!
First of all it has a lot of syntax errors:

- you've forgotten to close quotes after labels '*Masculine*' and '*Others*'
- you've mistyped the third '*FormControlLabel*' and you've typed '*From*' instead of '*Form*'

beside these syntax errors your code worked well and Parent's state updated correctly as soon as I changed gender.

Parent.js

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './Child';

const Parent = () => {
  const initialValues = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    gender: ''
  };
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValues);
  console.log("Parent's state", state);
  const handler = (e) => {
    setState({
      ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  return (
    <ChildComponent handler={handler} {...state} />
  )
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {FormControl,RadioGroup, FormControlLabel, Radio} from '@material-ui/core';

const Child = (props) => {
  const { fristName, lastName, gender, handler } = props;
  console.log('child's props', props);
  return (
    <FormControl component='fieldset'>
        <RadioGroup onChange={handler} name='gender' value={gender}>
            <FormControlLabel value='feminine' control={<Radio />} label='Feminine' />
            <FormControlLabel value='masculine' control={<Radio />} label='Masculine' />
            <FormControlLabel value='others' control={<Radio />} label='Others' />
        </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  )
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: hmm.. is it because I placed the console.log in the wrong place? i placed it in the handler function.

Comment: That's exactly the case. state doe not change immediately but changes to it can be observed in the next render cycle.